# Is there a huge difference between 1.6amp and 3amp power usage?

Tags: electrical, powertools

I just want to know if there a huge difference between 1.6 amp and 3 amp power usage.

Comment: 1.4 amperes, or almost double (or half depending on what type of person you are).

Comment: -1 very low quality question. Mathematically, this is a subtraction question. If it's a more complicated situation than that, we don't have enough detail here to give a good answer.

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on:

- hours used a day (lets assume 10)
- days used a week (assume 7)
- rate charged by your power company (assume 13 cents per kilowatt
  hour)

Under these assumptions, the difference is about $500 a year.

You can refer to the chart below if you want to change the hours, days, or rate.

[image]